# Are there any known issues when using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools on “Windows Server 2019 Datacenter”

Tags: visual-studio-2019, performance-testing, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019, vstest

We have a set of performance and stress test written with the **Microsoft Visual Studio Test Tools** and recently those test stopped working on all but one of our virtual machines.

The virtual machine where the test is still working is still using “Windows Server 2016 Datacenter” while the virtual machines which don't work any more have been updated to “Windows Server 2019 Datacenter”.

There is also a slight difference between the used Microsoft Visual Studio. The working system us using “Enterprise 2019 Version 16.7.3” while the system which don't work use the slightly newer “Enterprise 2019 Version 16.10.0”.

On the machines which don't work any more we get the following error:

> Could not run Web test 'XXXXX' on agent 'XXXXXX': Could not access table 'Test#csv' in data source 'dsTest' of test 'XXXXXX,XXXXXX': The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.

And I was able to pinpoint the problem to the following statement:

```cs
    using WebTesting = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;

    [WebTesting.DataSource (
        dataSourceName: "dsTest",
        providerName: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV",
        connectionString: "|DataDirectory|\\data\\Test.csv",
        WebTesting.DataBindingAccessMethod.Sequential,
        WebTesting.DataBindingSelectColumns.SelectOnlyBoundColumns,
        tableName: "Test#csv")]
```

Are there any known problems when using Microsoft Visual Studio Test Tools on “Windows Server 2019 Datacenter” and/or “Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.7.3”?

And if so are there any fixes and workaround I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there was a bug introduced in 16.10.#. Supposed to be fixed in upcoming release.

[VS2019 1610-upgrade-breaks-MSTest-DataSource](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/1610-upgrade-breaks-MSTest-DataSourceAt/1468870)